# is trim enabled for my encrypted home directory?

Tags: ssd

I encrypted my home drive after installation with ecryptfs-migrate-home. How to I check if ssd trim is on? I looked in /etc/cron.weekly but I do not see fstrim. Ive read conflicting things when I try to look for information. On one hand people say trim is on by default, but other sources say trim is disabled by default on encrypted partitions because of security. So I would like to confirm whether my home partition needs to be manually trimmed.

Using ubuntu 18.04